# Show a <div> due to database request (portal field)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a JS beginner and using the following script, which is working well with a checkbox.

```js
function adressfreigabe() {
  var objektadresse = document.getElementById("objektadresse");
  var adresseeinblenden = document.getElementById("adresseeinblenden");
  adresseeinblenden.style.display = (objektadresse.checked) ? "" : "none";
}
```

```html
<h4>
  <!-- Adresse einblenden --><input id="objektadresse" onchange="adressfreigabe()" type="checkbox" wtx-context="BBCF87B1-40E3-47D2-8436-F8C2B75940EF" /> Objektadresse erfassen und ver&ouml;ffentlichen</h4>

<p>Bitte geben Sie die Objektadresse hier nur ein, wenn sie ver&ouml;ffentlicht werden darf.</p>

<div id="adresseeinblenden" margin-top="2em" style="display:none">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Stra&szlig;e</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <wstag class="wsTag" id="266" type="ddbf_67" widget="text">Portal Field :: strasse</wstag>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Hausnummer</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <wstag class="wsTag" id="275" type="ddbf_70" widget="text">Portal Field :: hausnummer</wstag>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility to replace the checkbox by the result of a database request (text, "yes" or "no")?

The `<div id="adresseeinblenden"...>` should be shown if the result is "yes" and should be hidden if the result is "no".

The field which delivers the result looks like this:

```
<wstag class="wsTag" id="5853" type="ddbf_197" widget="select">Portal Field :: adresseeinblenden</wstag>
```

I don't need onclick etc, there is no action from the user required to show the div.

Comment: are you still facing issue ?

Comment: yes, i am still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery, ajax.
You can call your fetch from db function using ajax in `$( document ).ready(function(){}.`

Assign the db result to lets say a variable, dbRes.

And then replace your condition *`adresseeinblenden.style.display = (objektadresse.checked) ? "" : "none"; }`* with `adresseeinblenden.style.display = (dbRes == 'yes') ? "" : "none"; }`

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```js
function adressfreigabe(res) {
  var objektadresse = document.getElementById("objektadresse");
  var adresseeinblenden = document.getElementById("adresseeinblenden");
  adresseeinblenden.style.display = (res == "yes") ? "" : "none";
}
```

```html
<h4>
  <!-- Adresse einblenden --><input id="objektadresse" onchange="adressfreigabe(this.checked?'yes':'no')" type="checkbox" wtx-context="BBCF87B1-40E3-47D2-8436-F8C2B75940EF" /> Objektadresse erfassen und ver&ouml;ffentlichen</h4>

<p>Bitte geben Sie die Objektadresse hier nur ein, wenn sie ver&ouml;ffentlicht werden darf.</p>

<div id="adresseeinblenden" margin-top="2em" style="display:none">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>Stra&szlig;e</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <wstag class="wsTag" id="266" type="ddbf_67" widget="text">Portal Field :: strasse</wstag>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h4>Hausnummer</h4>
        </td>
        <td>
          <wstag class="wsTag" id="275" type="ddbf_70" widget="text">Portal Field :: hausnummer</wstag>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Zulqarnain,
thanks.
The "input" should be replaced by the result from the database. What can I use instead? div?
Where do I have to place my database field?
Something like this?
   var = res (<database field>);

Comment: you just need to call the function like this **adressfreigabe(<database field>)**

Comment: Aaah... I will try this. And instead of "input" I have to use "span" because of "onchange", right?

Answer (score 0):

After you fetch the data from your database, update the element style. For example, you could use jquery to make your get request and update styles:

```
$.get("https://database-url.com", function(data, status){
    if(data.attribute == "yes"){
        $("#objektadresse").css("display", "inline");
    }
    else{
        $("#objektadresse").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all!

I modified my code and it works!
Here is the working code:

```html
<div id="objektadresse" onload="adressfreigabe(dbRes)">
  <div id="adresseeinblenden" margin-top="2em" style="display:none">Table or Text (adress) to be shown if the database field shows the text &quot;Yes&quot; (in German &quot;Ja&quot;)</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(adressfreigabe) {
      var dbRes = '<wstag class="wsTag" id="5853" type="ddbf_197" widget="select">Portal Field :: provisionspflichtig</wstag>';
      var objektadresse = document.getElementById("objektadresse");
      var adresseeinblenden = document.getElementById("adresseeinblenden");
      adresseeinblenden.style.display = (dbRes == 'Ja') ? "" : "none";
    })
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.